# Spring boot API criteria returning multiple times

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I am beginning with spring boot and JPA 2.0.
My api runs a query from a mysql db that has a single record. 
For some reason the API is returning the query resultset nonstop.

Funny is that if I return the size of the Vector it works fine, but when I return the List<> it runs multiple times the same code.

I suspect that I might have to set some flag for connection stoppage or something.
Any ideas of what might be causing this?

```
//controller
    @RestController
    public class ClientController {


            @RequestMapping("/client")
            public List<Client> client(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {

                Client clientModel = new Client();
                List<Client> clients = clientModel.getClients();

                //return clients.size();
                return clients;


            }
    }





    //model
    public List<Client> getClients() {

            try {
                EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
                        .createEntityManagerFactory("CRM");
                EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
                CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
                CriteriaQuery<Client> q = cb.createQuery(Client.class);
                Root<Client> c = q.from(Client.class);
                q.select(c);
                List<Client> clients = em.createQuery(q).getResultList();
                // ArrayList<Client> clients = (ArrayList<Client>) q.select(c);
                em.close();
                emf.close();

                return clients;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

Comment: are you sure you only have one record in the DB?

Comment: I'm positive. The API keeps returning multiple lists with the same record. When I uncomment the .size() call it returns 1. Also, when I run it in debug mode the breakpoint hits multiple times in the method call.

Comment: @wdoering I believe the problem is not in the code you posted - it's likely in your frontend. Could you test the relevant REST API using [curl](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DURACLOUDDOC/REST+API+Examples+Using+curl) or [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and tell us again what happens?

Answer (score 1):

Didn't find the root cause of the problem but found a solution.
In the first version I was implementing the query in the same class where I defined my Client @entity. 
I have created a different class 'ClientRepository' and moved the query into it. 
The problem stopped.

I guess JPA doesn't like that...